# Mark radio checked even if it's disabled

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to mark a radio button as checked with `click()`, but that doesn't work if the radio is disabled.

What should I do?

Comment: But I should add that disabled form elements are not sent to the server, maybe you want to make it `readonly` instead.

Comment: Check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935385/mark-radio-checked-even-if-its-disabled#answer-11936171 i think its what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `.prop()` method. `.attr()` is difficult to detect cross-browser truthy-ness

```
$('input:radio:disabled').prop('checked', true);
```

^This would automatically make any disabled ones checked.

If you wanted it to be on some sort of click Event etc... you would do:

```
$('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
```

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m6K9x/)

Answer (score 1):

only solution is from javascript/jquery - (simplest example with jquery)

```
<input type="radio" id="test" name="test_name" disabled="disabled" />

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').attr('checked', 'checked');      
});​
```

see this jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/7XevT/1/

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can do this is to put an element (e.g. div) in front of the radio button and check for clicks on that.

Mouse events are disabled on disabled elements (for good reason... you've DISABLED it!)

There is probably a better way to do what you want however. I can't imagine anyone clicking a disabled radio button. Plus, if you want a radio button to be clickable then don't disable it!

Comment: He is probably wanting to do this programatically to use as a marker for something in his code.  Or there is a case where one radio is dependent upon another elements value but you don't want the user to be able to change its state.

Comment: Ah i see, I read the question as he wanted to capture click events on the actual radio button.

Answer (score 0):

The `click` event* is the wrong approach to use. Disabled elements don't react to being clicked on (because they've been disabled), so it does no good to trigger a `click` event.

`<input type="radio" />` and `<input type="checkbox" />` elements have a `checked` property that needs to be modified to change their checked state:

#### With plain JS:

```
<input id="r" type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" disabled />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('r').checked = true;
</script>
```

#### With jQuery:

```
<input id="r" type="radio" name="foo" value="bar" disabled />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#r').prop('checked', true);
</script>
```

<sub>* or function, can't tell which you're using. I assume it's `jQuery.fn.click`, which triggers an event.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` input doesn't trigger the click event. A hackish way is to wrap a radio by another element:

```
<span class='radio'><input type='radio' disabled/></span>
```

```
$('.radio').click(function(){
  var $input = $(this).find('input'); 
  $input.prop('checked', !$input.prop('checked'))
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K8ADL/)

But I'm not sure why an input should be `disabled` when it's checked state can be changed!!

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the game, but you can add a temp `<span>` that can lay over the radio button, that will give the effect that you're clicking on it:

```
$('input[disabled="disabled"]').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<span style="position:relative;"></span>')
        $(this).parent().append('<span class="disabled" style="left:0; top:0; position:absolute; display:block; width:100%; height:100%;">&nbsp;</span>');
})

$('.disabled').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().removeAttr('disabled').attr('checked', 'checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled').unwrap();
    $(this).remove();
})
```

Check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FTymF/

You can also toggle the disabled radio button:

```
$('.disabled').click(function(){
    if($(this).prev().attr('checked'))
        $(this).prev().removeAttr('disabled').removeAttr('checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    else
         $(this).prev().removeAttr('disabled').attr('checked','checked').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```

Check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/FTymF/1/